# Chrome Extension | Create manifest.json dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, web-deployment, manifest.json

I am new to chrome extension development. I'm working on a chrome extension where I'd like to inject or create manifest.json dynamically.

Could you guys please tell me whether it is possible or not?

**Why do I want to create manifest.json dynamically?**

Here the requirement is content scripts need to be executed in a different groups of match URLs.

For example, if I have two content scripts, content1.js and content2.js, then

content1.js shall execute on list = [url1, url2, url3], whereas

content2.js needs to work in [url4, url5, url6]

**Use Case:**

The extension will take user name/team name, and based on the entitlement rule it will receive a list of script name from backend, which will be fed as content scripts of manifest.json. And that needs to create dynamically.

Note:

1. All the scripts will be stored in a repository.
2. Entitlement Rule is something that will decide the list of script name, return from backend.

I am not sure whether it is possible or not and because of that, I have reached out to you guys. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the manifest is needed to install the extension, if the extension needs to retrieve a manifest, then it'll need to be installed first, but you can't, without a manifest - see the issue? also, even if it could be done, such an extension where the manifest is not "fixed" will never be passed by google (I'm assuming my vague memory of googles vetting of extensions is correct)

Comment: @JaromandaX, thank you for your reply. But that means manifest.json can not be created dynamically? Is there any alternate approach where I can implement my use case?

Comment: Use chrome.declarativeContent API with RequestContentScript action (the documentations says it's experimental but it works).